# why does my Query not load or take so long?

Tags: sql, join, ssms

I already had a query which showed the wrong details (cg_Tracking.Distance), which I now tried to change by changing it, from cg_tracking.distance to  but it seems not to load.

it was like this before and showed results very fast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cg_tracking.f_nr, 
                cg_tracking.date_cg, 
                cg_tracking.manummer,
                cg_tracking.distance, 
                cg_tracking.longitude, 
                cg_tracking.latitude, 
                cg_tracking.datetime_cg, 
                cg_tracking.speed 
FROM   cg_tracking
WHERE f_nr = '317' 
GROUP  BY cg_tracking.f_nr, 
          cg_tracking.date_cg, 
          cg_tracking.manummer, 
          cg_trackign.Distance. 
          cg_tracking.longitude, 
          cg_tracking.latitude, 
          cg_tracking.datetime_cg, 
          cg_tracking.speed 
ORDER  BY cg_tracking.date_cg ASC
```

Now I´ve changed it to this and it takes really long to load and doesn't even give me the right details.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cg_tracking.f_nr, 
                cg_tracking.date_cg, 
                cg_tracking.manummer,
                Round(( cg_01_ziele.strecke / 1000 ), 1) AS Strecke, 
                cg_tracking.longitude, 
                cg_tracking.latitude, 
                cg_tracking.datetime_cg, 
                cg_tracking.speed 
FROM   cg_tracking, cg_01_Ziele
                        JOIN cg_zielfahrtstatuslog
                          ON cg_ZielfahrtstatusLog.ZielID = cg_01_Ziele.ZielID
                        JOIN cg_02_kunden 
                          ON cg_02_kunden.zielid = cg_01_ziele.zielid
WHERE cg_tracking.F_NR = '317' 
                        AND NOT( cg_zielfahrtstatuslog.status = 7 
                                 AND cg_zielfahrtstatuslog.interruption = 0)
       AND cg_01_Ziele.DATETIME_CG between '2020-06-02T00:00:00' 
       AND '2020-06-02T23:59:59'
GROUP  BY cg_tracking.f_nr, 
          cg_tracking.date_cg, 
          cg_tracking.manummer, 
          Round(( cg_01_ziele.strecke / 1000 ), 1), 
          cg_tracking.longitude, 
          cg_tracking.latitude, 
          cg_tracking.datetime_cg, 
          cg_tracking.speed 
ORDER  BY cg_tracking.date_cg ASC
```

It always gives me other F_NR and Datetime_cg eventhough I wrote where F_nr = '317' and between the dates I wanted.
I already deleted the and Not conditions and it still takes a lot of time and doesn't give me the right answer.
My assumption is because of the Joins and different tables but I don't know any solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the query in the SSMS query performance analyzer?  You might need to add some indexes (I'm thinking about cg_zielfahrtstatuslog.status or cg_zielfahrtstatuslog.interruption)

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or "portal"? Please [edit] your question to use appropriate tags, like what database you're using. You should also include the schema and some sample data.

Comment: You probably have a million record or more ? Right ?

Comment: @Neil is right, proper indexation is the key, you need to learn everything about indexes, and the difference between the two main ones : https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-the-difference-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-indexes-in-sql-server/

Comment: sorry I was so focused on programming and Im working with C# so I just wrote that,

Comment: For your specific query, you don't need both of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` because the expressions in the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause are the same as the ones in the `GROUP BY` clause. So I suggest removing the `GROUP BY`. Might not affect performance but does affect readability.

Comment: Why is `cg_tracking` missing in any of the join conditions? Are you really after a carthesian product here?